# Unmet dependencies, but package already installed. Tried apt-get -f install, but will only remove needed package

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I have an unmet dependencies problem. This makes me unable to install or remove any packages. However, I have already installed the package that is required (libpng12). Here is the result of 'sudo apt-get install libpng12-0'.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpng12-0:i386 is already the newest version (1.2.54-1ubuntu1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried 'sudo apt-get -f install', but it will only ask to remove the the 'cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk'. Removing it will fix the issue, but the package is required for my network printer, so the printer will stop working.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dleyna-server gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon libcolord-gtk1
  libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1 libdleyna-core-1.0-3 libgoa-backend-1.0-1
  libgssdp-1.0-3 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3
  libnss-myhostname realmd
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8,733 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.